# Is it possible to automatically activate Focus on the weekend?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I already configured Focus to enable between 7pm and 7am, because this is a period i am not working and do not want to receive Windows notifications.

But i did not find anything related to weekends. I would like to always enable Focus on the weekend, so i am not bothered by notifications on saturday and sunday.

Besides manually activating it every saturday, is there a way to schedule a task to do this automatically i mean, activate focus on saturday and deactivate it on early monday ?

Comment: Do you mean "Focus" or "Do not disturb" ? The later can be set to "Weekends" in *Settings > Notifications*.

Answer (score 1):

The Focus Settings in Windows 11 (I have Windows 11 Pro) are daily, not 5 days per week.

So at this point in time, you cannot do what you wish automatically. You will need to set at the end of the Weekend for the 5 days coming.